# Are there way to controll the memory usage per user in MySQL.MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, limit, quota

In the interactive query form sometimes my users are making wrong joins and query generates huge amount of data after doing while.
How can I prevent the user to use more than certain amount of memory?

I would like to limit the memory usage per query...

I am using mysql 5.5.8 myisam engine.

Thanks Arman.

Comment: this may help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySQL has no per-user memory quota ability.

How much memory a single query can use is dictated by many variables you can configure. You can limit the size of join buffers, sort buffers, temporary tables, etc. These limits will be global for all queries.

Comment: What do you mean per process? There is only one MySQL process.

Comment: per mysql process: when you do show processlist in mysql you can see the query process ID, but I cannot see the memory usage of that process(mysql internal process)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MyISAM let's you control this on a per thread basis.

You can always use

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

and KILL any processes that have been running for certain length of time.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am controlling the time live of query by events: every job which is running more than 5hours is killed.